# Search for a file with wildcards in the path using Windows command line

Tags: windows, command-line, search, powershell, wildcards

How can I search for files in the Windows command line, using wildcards like this?

```
C:\Users\*\AppData\Local\*.txt
```

Comment: For what are you trying to use the wildcard search?  A command line program, .bat file?  For a .bat file scenario, just use nested batch for loops. `for /d %%D in (C:\Users\*) do for %%F in (%%~fD\AppData\Local\*.txt) do
 echo %%~fF`  As for command line programs, the wildchar handling is up to the authors of that specific program.

Comment: I am trying to search in some path with wildcards in the path, not only in the file name, I need some way using existing windows tools (cmd.exe), or powershell, or some external free tool!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Windows PowerShell can do this easily.

```
Get-ChildItem C:\Users\*\AppData\Local\*.txt
```

If you want to include subfolders:

```
Get-ChildItem C:\Users\*\AppData\Local\*.txt -recurse
```

Regarding Hidden (etc.) files, Powershell's `help Get-ChildItem` says:

> By default, Get-ChildItem gets non-hidden items, but you can use the
>   Directory, File, Hidden, ReadOnly, and System parameters to get only
>   items with these attributes. To create a complex attribute search, use
>   the Attributes parameter. If you use these parameters, Get-ChildItem
>   gets only the items that meet all search conditions, as though the
>   parameters were connected by an AND operator.

Comment: How to include hidden and system dirs and files?

Comment: @MohamedSakherSawan check out the edit I added.

Answer (score 5):

Any good Unix shell for Windows will do this.

For example, here's a screenshot of my [Hamilton C shell](http://hamiltonlabs.com/Cshell.htm) doing your example (sorry, no matches) and a couple others that do produce matches.   The [`...` wildcard](http://hamiltonlabs.com/UserGuide/31-Wildcarding.htm) used in the third example matches zero or more directory levels, whatever it takes for the rest of the pattern to match.

[image: Wildcarding using Hamilton C shell on Windows 7 x64]

And here's how you might do it with [Cygwin](http://cygwin.org) `bash`.  A few differences here because Cygwin follows Unix conventions:  Paths are usually typed with forward slashes and the backslash is the escape character.  Since Unix doesn't understand drive letters, they've introduced a `/cydrive/c` notation to refer to the `C:` drive.  As on Unix, wildcarding is case-sensitive.  And while it supports the usual multiple directory level wildcarding you'd like, it doesn't include the `...` I added to my shell.  (Instead, you'd probably use `find`.)

[image: Wildcarding using Cygwin bash on Windows 7 x64]

Answer (score 2):

In cmd, navigate to `C:\Users`, and run

`dir /s /b | findstr AppData\Local | findstr txt`

Explanation: `dir /s` lists all files recursively, `/b` displays full path, and within all these child files, use pipeline operator to search both the string 'AppData\Local' and 'txt'.

Comment: Instead of navigating to C:\Users\, I guess you could give the path as argument to dir.